# Using Regex and DefaultTableModel to insert values into JTable

Tags: java, regex, jtable, twitter4j, defaulttablemodel

I'm building a Twitter client and I wan't to retrieve and display the world wide trends. So far (thanks somewhat to the help of Stack Overflow) I can retrieve the trend info, pull the necessary info from it and post the trends to the console. When I try and add the trends to the table, I only ever am able to display the first trend multiple times, and I'm unsure where I'm going wrong with my row creation etc.

A fresh pair of eyes would be appreciated!

Thanks

```
public static void WorldWideTrends() {
    Trends WorldWideTrendsList;

    try {

        WorldWideTrendsList = getTrends();
        UI.whatIsDisplayedList.removeAll();
        UI.tweetModel = new DefaultTableModel(10, 1);
        String trendsInfo = WorldWideTrendsList.toString();

        System.out.println(trendsInfo);

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(#.*?)\\'", Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(trendsInfo);

        while (matcher.find()) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                String output = matcher.group(0);

                System.out.println(output);
                UI.tweetModel.insertRow(1, new Object[] {});
                UI.tweetModel.setValueAt(
                        "<html><body style='width: 400px;'><strong>"
                                + output + "</strong><html><br>", i, 0);
            }
        }

    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    UI.whatIsDisplayedList.setModel(UI.tweetModel);

}
```

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the purpose of this is:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       String output = matcher.group(0);
       ...
    }
}
```

but it will process each match 10 times. Just calling `.group()` again doesn't take you to the next match, you need to call `.find()` again.

I think you want to simply remove the for-loop (but this will match more than 10 times, if more than 10 matches exist), or maybe remove the while-loop and do something like:

```
// process the first 10 matches
// no while-loop!
for (int i = 0; i < 10 && matcher.find(); i++) {
   String output = matcher.group(0);
   ...
}
```